# how to validate a json empty object in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, validation, foreach

my php code works fine when it returns the result like this ->

```
{
"id": 267935,
"results": [
{
"key": "rc94yWXcyr0",
"name": "Trailer 1",
"site": "YouTube"
},
{  
"key": "GZ0Bey4YUGI",
"name": "Official Trailer",
"site": "YouTube"
},
{
"key": "y1fZg0hhBX8",
"name": "Official Trailer 2",
"site": "YouTube"
}
]
}
```

but i get **error**

> (Notice: Undefined variable: finaltrailers in ... )

when results return like **this -->**

```
{
"id": 392344,
"results": [

]
}
```

and this is my **php code -->**

```
  $trailer = $json2['results'];
    foreach($trailer as $trailers=>$keytrailers){
                       foreach($keytrailers as $alltrailers=>$allkeytrailers){
                           if($alltrailers == 'key'){
                           @ $finaltrailers .=  $allkeytrailers.',';
                           }
                       }
                   }
echo trim($finaltrailers,",");
```

how can i validate the empty array and give and error my self ? please help me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the variable to use it in `trim`.
Just add it at the beginning of your code.

```
$finaltrailers = '';
$trailer = $json2['results'];

foreach($trailer as $trailers=>$keytrailers){
    foreach($keytrailers as $alltrailers=>$allkeytrailers){
        if($alltrailers == 'key'){
             @ $finaltrailers .=  $allkeytrailers.',';
        }
     }
}
echo trim($finaltrailers,",");
```